# python get content from website

Tags: python-3.x

I have website that have the content:

> "UserID":"321312","Name":"TestIt"

i try to get the UserID by python . but i didn't success with it.

it's not JSON or something it is normal webiste.

My Code:

```
import urllib.request
link = "sites.com/test"
a = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
print(a["UserID"])
```

my Result:

> None

I'm using python 3.

can anyone help me with it?

thanks

Comment: What do you get if you do `print(a)`?  I suspect because you're not parsing the response, there is no key `UserID` to output

Comment: i get the all website source code. i just want the UserID

Comment: Post a sample of the website's source code that contains the `userid`

Comment: i give the relevant content for that. it's everything with html code.

Comment: You won't get much help unless you provide us with more details/code  about the problem.

Comment: I just want to open the url , and serach the word " UserID" and then

Comment: print the "321312" as the id

Comment: We need to code to be able to help you!

Comment: @art20170 without the html source we don't know if `UserID` is a parameter of an `<a>` tag or if it's inside it's content **i.e.:** `<a userId=123 href='example.com'></a>` or `<a href='example.com'>UserID=123</a>`. If you wan't us to help you, first you must help us.

Comment: i try this also. but it's not on a . it's look like " [{"UserID":"140556086035398","UserName":testit"}]," , this is not json or something else. the devloper do it as text

Comment: good exmple for that same thing, if you go to : https://www.facebook.com/apple . and then view source you will see the ""pageID":"434174436675167" . like this i need to get the ID . almost the same thing.